# Insert query is not working properly in c# window

Tags: c#, window

I am creating a window application and I've chosen a database from the New Item menu. My insert query below is not executing:

```
con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into record values('" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "','" + textBox9.Text + "','" + textBox10.Text + "','" + textBox11.Text + "','"+textBox13.Text+"','"+textBox12.Text+"')", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: What error(s) are you getting back? Have you checked that your string concatenation is producing what you think it should? Have you copied that string into SQLSMS and executed it directly to see if it works?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

In Sql when your Insert query does not contain the column names then the values have to be in the correct order. Maybe this is why it is failing. You did not provide us with an error so i dont know.

You are trying this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

I am suggesting to try this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

Comment: Actully problem is that when my program is in running mode at that time its working ,means data is inserting but when i am showing table data there is no data.

Comment: if you are using a Db transaction then you have to commit the transaction

Answer (score 0):

If you can you should use parameters and include your column names (like how Andreas suggested) . An example would be...

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO record (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (@data1, @data2, @data3,...)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data1", textbox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data2", textbox3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data3", textbox4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("...", ...);

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: Actully problem is that when my program is in running mode at that time its working ,means data is inserting but when i am showing table data there is no data.

Comment: @Gauravshukla Where are you attempting to show the data?  In the windows form or in a manager type program?